# How to flip image in android

Tags: android, flip

I have 1 image , I want to click of that image then it show the text(number in pic) which is placed in that image some second eg 30 sec, after 30 second it back to original position or original state.
How to it occurs in android.

[image]
[image] [image]

before click image ......when click image(flip image)....after 30 second image automatically back position 1.

> **State 1:**
>
> Donot display any text just showing image only
>
> **state 2:** Click that image, flip and show value which is randomly generated. it takes (hold) time 30 second.
>
> **State 3:**
> After 30 second automatically filping original position or state 1.

...

> **Note:**
>
> How to hold 30 second that fliping image

When, I am using this.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

 <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="100%"
        android:duration="500"
        android:repeatCount="2"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:startOffset="400"/>

   </set>
```

In state two image display number only by fliping image when image click.
Anyone have idea behind this please give comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your layout:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30 sec" android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Make click listener on image view:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // Rotate image here

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    // Rotate image to original position
                }
            }, 30000); // 30000 time in milis

        }
    });
```

Comment: Is that best idea using ViewFliper by filping or not? you have any idea how to flip image? just like my images.

Comment: How to hold 30 second that fliping image - use new Handler().postDelayed